# Geo location suggestion

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

Is there any way to achieve auto completing as similar to the http://maps.google.com where it directly start doing suggestions even if I type a single letter?

I know theres this `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` class however I definetly need to suggest for a single country and this is not possible with this API due to lack of settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should specify bounds parameter in the request.

> bounds is a google.maps.LatLngBounds  object specifying the area in which to search for Places. The results are biased towards, but not restricted to, Places contained within these bounds.

see: http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html#places_autocomplete